# Regex - How to find all occurrence of commands inserts in a text (Batch SQL)

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, regex-group

I need to find all occurrence of inserts commands inside a string. (In the middle of the insert can have a break line)

For example:

```
  ...

    SOME COMMAND TEXT

    SOME COMMAND TEXT 

    INSERT INTO table (CAMPO 1, CAMPO 2) 
VALUES (1, 'some text in (parentheses) ')

    SOME COMMAND TEXT

    INSERT INTO table (CAMPO 1, CAMPO 2) VALUES (1, 2) 

    SOME COMMAND TEXT BELOW INSERT IN THE SAME LINE

    INSERT INTO table (CAMPO 1, CAMPO 2) VALUES (1, 2);INSERT INTO table (CAMPO 1, CAMPO 2) VALUES (1, 2);INSERT INTO table (CAMPO 1, CAMPO 2) VALUES (1, 2)

    SOME COMMAND TEXT 

    INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1) ;
    INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1) ;

    SOME COMMAND TEXT  
    SOME COMMAND TEXT  

    ...
```

In this case, I need to get with a regex all inserts

Can you guys help me, please?

Comment: What have you tried? How is the code behaving differently than what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`/^INSERT.+$/gm`](https://regexr.com/3tbdv). Checks for beginning of line (`^`), `INSERT` (`INSERT`), any character (`.`) any (non-zero) number of times (`+`), end of line (`$`). The anchors `^` and `$` ensure that the entire line matches. The `m` modifier treats multiple line strings as separate lines rather than a single large line. The `g` modifier will ensure that we do not stop at the first match.

If you would like to match specific components of the statement, you could use `/^INSERT INTO (.+) VALUES (.+)$/gm` and access the components through capture groups.

If you might have line breaks within the insert statements, you should try using `/^INSERT INTO ((?:.|\n)+?) VALUES ((?:.|\n)+?)$/gm`. With `(?:.|\n)+?` we're matching any character including newlines non-greedily.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, the problem is that in the middle of the insert can have a break line, how can I ignore it in this case?

Comment: @DiegoGermano Try `^INSERT INTO ((?:.|\n)+?) VALUES ((?:.|\n)+?)$`.

Comment: how possible the regex work when ( or ) didn't contain \ to handle escape character and your applying ^ & $ for paring 1 full text string scenario

Comment: @SKLTFZ by using the `/m` modifier like I did in my answer. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Hi Thanks again, but did not work,  of the insert values can have text like 'some text in (parentheses) ' and have more insert in the same line

Answer (score 0):

to capture all the insert statement.
You can use

```
(INSERT INTO(?s:.)*?VALUES(?s:.)*?\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/tejrDM/4 shows the result of output

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! the problem is that in the middle of the insert can have a break line, how can I ignore it in this case?

Comment: please check the update answer, you need to include newline when trying to fetch the matched substring

Comment: Hi Thanks again, but I just get one more issue, inside of the insert values can have text like 'some text in (parentheses) ', it possible in this case?

Comment: no, you properly need explicit terminate expression for your case, since your query accept newline, no explicit ending expression, it properly cannot work